# Read cell from SQL Column dynamically

Tags: c#, sql

I have problem for reading data from huge SQL table which contain 420 column and 13500 row.

I want to convert table to 3 column by this code i solved my problem to converting

```
foreach (var item in mytable)
{
    var result = db.mytable.Where(t => t.TaskID == item.TaskID).Select(e => e).Single();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            if (result != null)
            {
                valmat = result.GetType().GetProperties().Where(a => a.Name == "_" + i.ToString()).Select(p => p.GetValue(result, null)).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            }


            if (valmat!=null)
            {   
                WeekTB week = new WeekTB();
                week.ColumnID = Convert.ToInt32(i);
                week.Taskid = Convert.ToInt32(item.TaskID);
                week.ValueWeek = Convert.ToDouble(valmat);
                //db.WeekTBs.InsertOnSubmit(week);
                Console.WriteLine("taskID:" + item.TaskID + " Column:" + i + " Value:" + valmat);

                valmat = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I don't have any problem for reading data but my problem is slowing in reading data because my table have a lot null and it take to long to get value?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My ultimate advice is to change your database design. But if it is not possible you can start working with this line :

```
valmat = result.GetType().GetProperties().Where(a => a.Name == "_" + i.ToString()).Select(p => p.GetValue(result, null)).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

Your type is same for all the iterations and you are enumerating properties and filtering them for every iteration.
I would suggest something like this :

```
var columnNames  = Enumerable.Range(0,200).Select(t=> "_"+t).ToArray();
var properties typeof(MyTable).GetProperties()
.Where(t=>columnNames.Contains(t.Name))
.ToDictionary(t=> t.Name); // outside of the loop

valmat = properties["_"+i].GetValue(result,null); //inside of the loop
```

Comment: my problem is here  ((( properties["_"+i].GetValue(result,null);)))  it too long to get value

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem by converting Excel file to SCV file .it too fast
for Excel by 14000 row and 500 column when i using read excel by c# it take 3 hour but when changed Excel file to SCV file c# reed all data just in 3 sec